# How can I plot the time index for every subplot that are sharing x axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]I'm plotting a dataset of Time Series, they all have the same date, but since there's a lot of graphs I always have to scroll down to see the timestamp, how can I plot the x-axis index in every subplot?

```
%%time
var_list=list(produzioni_df.columns)
f, ax = plt.subplots(len(var_list),1,figsize=(32,32*len(var_list)/5), sharex=True)
for i, axi in enumerate(ax.flat):
    axi.plot(produzioni_df[var_list[i]], label='Time Series')
    for j in range(len(const_intervals_list[i])):
        axi.axvspan(const_intervals_list[i][j][0], const_intervals_list[i][j][-1], color='b', alpha=0.2)
    axi2=axi.twinx()
    #axi2.plot(2*(np.abs(fabbisogni_diff_df['%s_diff_1_perc'%var_list[i]])>fabbisogni_diff_df['%s_diff_1_perc'%var_list[i]].mean() 
    #        +3*fabbisogni_diff_df['%s_diff_1_perc'%var_list[i]].std()),'y',label='Outlier')
    axi2.plot(produzioni_df2['%s_outlier'%var_list[i]]*2,'y',label='Outlier')
    axi2.plot(produzioni_df[var_list[i]].isna(),'r',label='NaN')
    axi2.set_ylim([0, 20])
    axi2.set_yticks([0,20])
    axi2.legend()
    axi.set_ylabel(var_list[i])
    axi.legend()
```

This is part of the plot

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpEdB.png]

Answer (score 0):

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(len(var_list),1,figsize=(32,32*len(var_list)/5), sharex=True)
for i, axi in enumerate(ax.flat):
```

Did you try `sharex=False` or to remove sharex?

Comment: Yeah I tried with removing Sharex, and it works for this case, but in other cases plots might not have the same index, I wanted to share the x axis (so they look proportionate to eachother) and yet have the index under each plot.